# Issue with consuming web service in Java

Tags: java, web-services, jersey-2.0

I have the following requirement:

I need to send two parameters as (POST/PUT) in JSON body as request parameters for calling a web service.
Basically the web service will create new user and insert in database.

```
e.g. {"username":"a@a.com", "firstName":"AB"}
```

Now , the web service should be able to receive the JSON body and parse it.

```
    @PUT
    @Path("/add/user")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
       public int insertNewUser(User user) throws IOException{
       int result = userService.updateUser(user);
       return result;
       }
```

Below is the User class and it contains the getter , setter methods and the constructor.

```
{

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name="user")
//@JsonInclude(Include.NON_EMPTY)
public class User implements Serializable{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @XmlElement
    private String userName;
    @XmlElement
    private String firstName;

}
```

When the web service method insertNewUser is called , User user returns null.

Wanted to know , how to retrieve the JSON body which has been sent by the rest client.
How are the tags "username" and "firstName" , going to get the data from the JSON body.

Comment: Are you using Jersey?

Comment: using Jersey ....

Comment: And which version of Jersey are you using?

Comment: Version of Jersey 2.23

Comment: I really misunderstood the question. When you mentioned *how to retrieve the JSON body which has been sent by the rest client*, I thought it was about logging :/